Infinite summation of a falling factorial divided by a power
I'm trying to find the result of this summation
$$
S(r,m)=\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{(n)_m}{n^r}
$$
where $(r,m\in\mathbb{N})$, $(r\geq3)$, $(1\leq m \leq r-2)$ and $(n)_m=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ is a falling factorial.
I didn't know how to solve it, so I used WolframAlpha to compute $S(3,1)$, $S(4,1)$, $S(4,2)$, $S(5,1)$, $S(5,2)$, $S(5,3)$, $S(6,1)$, $S(6,2)$ ... $S(7,4)$, $S(7,5)$.
Even if I wouldn't know how to prove it, observing the results of these summations, I found out that $S(r,m)$ can be written as
$$
S(r,m) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{m \brack m-k}\zeta[r-(m-k)]
$$
where ${a \brack b}$ is a signed Stirling number of the first kind and $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.
So my questions are:

if it's true, how to prove it?
is there a smoother way to write and compute the result of $S(r,m)$ without involving Stirling numbers of the first kind and/or Riemann zeta?


UPDATE
Thanks to @Exodd suggestion, I've been able to prove it (and write it better!).
$$
S(r,m) = \sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{(n)_m}{n^r} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n)_m}{n^r}
$$
Given that
$$
\boxed{
(n)_m = \sum_{k=1}^{m}{m \brack k}(-1)^{m-k}n^k}
$$
so
$$
S(r,m) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{m}{m \brack k}(-1)^{m-k}n^{k-r} \\=
\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left( {m \brack k}(-1)^{m-k} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{r-k}}\right)
$$
and knowing that
$$
\boxed{
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}}
$$
we can write
$$
S(r,m) = \sum_{k=1}^{m}{m \brack k}(-1)^{m-k} \zeta(r-k)
$$
So, now the only question is

is there a smoother way to write and compute the result of $S(r,m)$ without involving Stirling numbers of the first kind and/or Riemann zeta?

I'm asking this because the implementation of $S(r,m)$ in Python is problematic, especially for large values of $r$ and $m$. This is what I'm currently doing
import numpy as np
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import stirling as S
from scipy.special import zeta as Z
# I tried with sympy zeta too, adding .n() to Z()
#from sympy.functions.special.zeta_functions import zeta as Z

def Srm(r,m):
    return np.sum([
            (S(m,i,signed=True)*1.)*
            (Z(r-i)*1.)
            for i in np.arange(1, m+1)
           ])

This is working for small values, for example
Srm(r=11, m=3)


4.13279753337381e-5

which is correct (see WolframAlpha clicking on more digits), but fails for larger values, for example
Srm(r=20, m=18)


-0.0741984832294336

that's obviously wrong, because $S(r,m)$ cannot be negative at all...
Any suggestion?

your formula is easy to prove by expanding $(n)_m$ with its taylor series (i.e. using the definition of Stirling numbers)
